# Replace occurrences swift regex

Tags: regex, swift, swift3

I'm trying to use the `String.replacingOccurrences` to change all occurrences of the following characters into commas:

`#.$[]`

However I can't seem to get it to accomplish this with what I have:

```
func cleanStr(str: String) -> String {
    return str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[.#$[/]]", with: ",", options: [.regularExpression])
}

print(cleanStr(str: "me[ow@gmai#l.co$m"))   // prints "me[ow@gmai,l,co,m\n"
```

Can anybody help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your pattern, `[.#$[/]]`, there is  a *character class union*, that is, it only matches `.`, `#`, `$` and `/` characters (a combination of two character classes, `[.#$]` and `[/]`).

In ICU regex, you need to escape literal square brackets `[` and `]` inside a character class:

```
"[.#$\\[/\\]]"
```

This code outputs `me,ow@gmai,l,co,m`:

```
func cleanStr(str: String) -> String {
    return str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[.#$\\[/\\]]", with: ",", options: [.regularExpression])
}
print(cleanStr(str: "me[ow@gmai#l.co$m"))
```